# Java (Apache POI) Detect cell bakground gold color

Tags: java, apache, colors, apache-poi

I've been searching for this but I couldn't find a solution.

I have a workbook and I have to check if a cell has the Excel Gold color as background.

something like:

```
if(cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor().equals(gold) ){ then do something
```

I tried with HSSF and RGB colors but I can't get it work.

I really apreciate some help.

THanks!

Comment: Did you try printing out the colour that POI finds for the cell in question?

Comment: Yes, but only as a short color. but I can't have the equals() working with short

Comment: What happens if you then look that short up in the palette, what colour does that give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
 if(cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColor()==HSSFColor.GOLD.index){
   //do whatever you want
 }
```

Comment: If you really think that any answer is the correct answer of your own question, mark that as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
if(cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColor().equals(HSSFColor.GOLD) ) 
{   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the wuick reply, but is not working, it seems that the HSSFColor.GOLD is different from the Excel gold