# How to get Excel Cell color using POI

Tags: apache-poi

I am developing a `Java Application`.

In my Application, I used `Excel` which is created by manually (WPS spread sheet tool in Ubuntu Machine) and gave style like Color, Bold and Italic.

Using POI, I can find all the styles but could not find the `Color`.

**Sample Code:-**

```
XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);  // j is loop iterate value
XSSFColor color = cell.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColorColor();
```

From the above code, I got only `Null` values from the all `Cell` and I was check with this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621527/get-cell-color-in-excel-with-poi) but no useful.

Please help me to solve this issues.

Comment: check this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17247773/6497884

Comment: @jonggu: I tried, but i am getting the value of 64 from all the Excel Cell.

Comment: I think you have to convert color id to color. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20835582/6497884

Comment: Here, the "palette" (palette.getColor(colorIdx)) means what from the link.

Comment: Have you tried `XSSFColor color = cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor();`? `Excel`s cell interior fills are pattern fills where fill background color is the color **behind** the pattern and fill foreground color is the color of the pattern and default pattern is solid fill. So fill foreground color will be visible in cells interior.

Comment: @Axel Richter: Yeah, I tried but i got null values from all the Cell.

Comment: What `apache poi` version are you using? Because there were bugs fixed related to cell fill up to current last stable version 3.17.

Comment: @AxelRichter: Oh okay, let me try with latest version bcoz now I am using POI version 3.9 only.